# is this map invertible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ open be smooth.

Define: $g: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ by $g(x) = (x,f(x))$ does the map $g^{-1}|_{M\cap U}$ exist and is it continuous? where $M = \text{graph}(f)$ and $U = \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$

i tried using hte inverse funciton theorem but the jacobian is not square so I cannot find a determinant. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the inverse map is given by $g^{-1}|_M(x,f(x)) = x = \pi((x,f(x)))$ where $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is the projection onto the first $n$ coordinates. That is, $g^{-1}|_{M} = \pi|_M$. Clearly this is a continuous map.

Comment: I need to show it on $M \cap U$ does that make a difference? For instance previously i showed $g(R^{n}) = M \cap U$ but i didn't really "prove" it.

Comment: Your $U$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so $M \cap U = M$...

Comment: of course my bad - may I ask how did you get the inverse to be $x$?

Comment: Check the definitions - $\pi|_{M} \circ g = \mathrm{id}|_{\mathbb{R^n}}$ and $g \circ \pi|_M = \mathrm{id}|_{M}$.

Comment: I understand that - however I wasn't able to guess that the inverse would be $x$ - what led you to that?

Comment: edit: nevermind - I see it now thanks!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my last comment - if you write the definitions, you will see that you have no choice. Call the inverse $h$. Then by definition you must have $h(g(x)) = x$ but $h(g(x)) = h(x,f(x))$ so $h(x,f(x)) = x$.

Comment: yes that's exactly how I saw it haha, thanks